# How do I check if a device is an emulator or a physical device?

Tags: flutter

I want to know if there is any way to find whether the device is an emulator or a physical device.

I don't want my app to be installed on an emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flutter_is_emulator](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_is_emulator) to identify emulator or simulator.

```
bool isAnEmulator = await FlutterIsEmulator.isDeviceAnEmulatorOrASimulator;
```

Inorder this to work, you need to install the app to the emulator/simulator first.

You can also use another popular flutter package [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) to do this.

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Is emulator: ${androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice}');

IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
print('Is simulator: ${iosInfo.isPhysicalDevice}');
```

Comment: Wow. I wasn't expecting that quick reply. I thought this will closed or downvoted. I will try and provide detailed answer for this question. Thanks for understanding the question. Voted up.

Comment: @Ironic You are welcome, also check the updated answer. I've included one more plugin

Comment: Thanks @Midhun I am sure it will help others too. This is general scenario.

Comment: I have raised one question in the morning. if you have time have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61472420/flutter-e-location-permissions-4794-flutter-result-object-is-null

Comment: I didn't find isPhysicalDevice in DeviceInfo plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know. Just for understanding what is ;G (4).

Comment: @Ironic That was a typo, please check and let me know if you face any issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [trust_fall](https://pub.dev/packages/trust_fall)

trust_fall has following checks :

Checks whether device JailBroken on iOS/Android?

```
bool isJailBroken = await TrustFall.isJailBroken;
```

Checks whether device is real or emulator

```
bool isRealDevice = await TrustFall.isRealDevice;
```

Can this device mock location - no need to root!

```
bool canMockLocation = await TrustFall.canMockLocation;
```

(ANDROID ONLY) Check if application is running on external storage

bool isOnExternalStorage = await TrustFall.isOnExternalStorage;
Check if device violates any of the above

```
bool isTrustFall = await TrustFall.isTrustFall;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try and let you  know. Voted up.

Comment: Trust fall is giving some runtime error. Looks like not compatible with Flutter latest version.

Comment: I checked the GitHub for this and found the issue is open there for a long time. My suggestion is not to use this plugin at the moment.

Comment: I don't think trust_fall uses null safety FYI

Answer (score 1):

Today will [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) to get info

```dart
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    print('Is emulator: ${androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice}');
    
    IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    print('Is simulator: ${iosInfo.isPhysicalDevice}');
```

Comment: I think this answer is the best since device_plus is discontinued.